# Using variables inside Twig functions

Tags: twig

I just can't get this to work:

It should set var_2 based on the URL query string value of var_1

The problem is where I call var_1 with   {{var_1}}

I've tried various other methods but all throw different errors.

```
// var_3 set elsewhere

{% set var_1 %}test-{{var_3}}{% endset %}

{% set var_2 = app.request.get({{var_1}}) %}

// need var_2 set for rest of script
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use another tag (`{{ ... }}`) inside a twig tag (`{% ... %}`). So this is not going to work:

```
{% set var_2 = app.request.get({{var_1}}) %}
```

A solution is to just put the variable in function argument:

```
{% set var_2 = app.request.get(var_1) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and often cannot) use {{ }} within twig logic. {{ }} is used to output something to the response. To use a variable in line just name the variable. Also remember that ~ will join strings, but some people don't like using it for some reason!

```
{% set var_1 = 'test-' ~ var_3 %}
{% set var_2 = app.request.get(var_1) %}
```